# Create multi-line text on path inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path, text-on-path

I have a curved path that I want to put multi-line text onto, as shown in the picture (the black line is the path).

When I select `Text > Put On Path`, it becomes a single line and pressing return doesn't split it up into two lines again

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest fix is perhaps to consider putting it on two paths.  Start with two concentric circles, and add each line of text to the circles separately. Move the text into position using the arc handles on the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to what billy has suggested… A path can be made of several visually independent segments traced in such a way that text will be spread on multiple lines.

In this scenario we will not be using the existing arc and associated handles nore the *Ellipse tool*, but the *Bezier curves tool* [image] to trace a path on top of the original shape. Beware that the order in which nodes are being inserted do matter for letters to stay on the same "side" of the path.

With the help of guides and the snapping feature for the path to follow the original shape, proceed as follows:
⋄ Add points for the 1rst segment and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> key to end it.
⋄ Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key only while adding the 1rst node for the 2nd segment (where the next line begins). Hit enter key once again to end the segment.
⋄ Text can now be "set on path", adjust nodes handles to fit your needs.
[image]
⋄ Set text path opacity to 0.